# c sockets multiple send/recv calls

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, send, recv

I'm learning about c socket programming. I'm very new to this so forgive me if the answer may seem obvious. So basically I want the client to send to the server two strings ( username and a password). Problem is that the server only receives the username and then closes connection.

Can anyone explain why is this happening and how can I get it to work as intended ?

client:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <ctype.h>          
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define PORT 20000
#define LENGTH 512 


void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Variable Definition */
    int sockfd; 
    int nsockfd;
    char revbuf[LENGTH]; 
    struct sockaddr_in remote_addr;

    /* Get the Socket file descriptor */
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Failed to obtain Socket Descriptor! (errno = %d)\n",errno);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Fill the socket address struct */
    remote_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    remote_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &remote_addr.sin_addr); 
    bzero(&(remote_addr.sin_zero), 8);

    /* Try to connect the remote */
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Failed to connect to the host! (errno = %d)\n",errno);
        exit(1);
    }
    else 
        printf("[Client] Connected to server at port %d...ok!\n", PORT);

    char username[20], pw[20],buff;
    int rc,rc2;

    printf("username: ");
    scanf("%s",username);  
    rc=send(sockfd, username, strlen(username)+1, 0);
    printf("\n");
    printf("password: ");
    scanf("%s",pw);     
    rc2=send(sockfd, pw, strlen(pw)+1, 0);


    close (sockfd);
    printf("[Client] Connection lost.\n");
    return (0);
}
```

server:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <ctype.h>          
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define PORT 20000 
#define BACKLOG 5
#define LENGTH 512 

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main ()
{
    /* Defining Variables */
    int sockfd; 
    int nsockfd; 
    int num;
    int sin_size; 
    struct sockaddr_in addr_local; /* client addr */
    struct sockaddr_in addr_remote; /* server addr */
    char revbuf[LENGTH]; // Receiver buffer

    /* Get the Socket file descriptor */
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Failed to obtain Socket Descriptor. (errno = %d)\n", errno);
        exit(1);
    }
    else 
        printf("[Server] Obtaining socket descriptor successfully.\n");

    /* Fill the client socket address struct */
    addr_local.sin_family = AF_INET; // Protocol Family
    addr_local.sin_port = htons(PORT); // Port number
    addr_local.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // AutoFill local address
    bzero(&(addr_local.sin_zero), 8); // Flush the rest of struct

    /* Bind a special Port */
    if( bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr_local, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Failed to bind Port. (errno = %d)\n", errno);
        exit(1);
    }
    else 
        printf("[Server] Binded tcp port %d in addr 127.0.0.1 sucessfully.\n",PORT);

    /* Listen remote connect/calling */
    if(listen(sockfd,BACKLOG) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Failed to listen Port. (errno = %d)\n", errno);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf ("[Server] Listening the port %d successfully.\n", PORT);

    int success = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

        if ((nsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr_remote, &sin_size)) == -1) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Obtaining new Socket Despcritor. (errno = %d)\n", errno);
            exit(1);
        }
        else 
            printf("[Server] Server has got connected from %s.\n", inet_ntoa(addr_remote.sin_addr));

        int rc,rc2;
        char username[20],pw[20];
        rc = recv(nsockfd, username, strlen(username), 0);
        printf(username);
        rc2 = recv(nsockfd, pw, strlen(pw), 0);

        printf("\n");
        printf(pw);


            success = 1;
            close(nsockfd);
            printf("[Server] Connection with Client closed. Server will wait now...\n");
           // while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in the server: What is the length character array that has not been initialized? It's ***not*** e.g. `strlen(username)`. First remember that strings have to be terminated by the null-character `'\0'`, then remember that the value of uninitialized local variables is *indeterminate* (and in reality seemingly random).

Comment: Never call printf directly with something you got from outside. Use format. printf("%s", username);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the server:
`recv(nsockfd, username, strlen(username), 0);`.

The third parameter must specify size of the buffer. However, `username` does not contain any data yet, so `strlen(username)` is undefined behavior and most probably returns something inappropriate. Use `sizeof(username)` instead. The same for password.

Also note that `recv` will read up to 20 bytes from the stream. So, unless `username` is guaranteed to be always 19 characters + `'\0'`, the first `recv` may (somewhat unexpectedly) read some characters from `password` as well, stealing them from the second `recv`. There are no message boundaries in a TCP stream.

Comment: "theoretically you might read both username and password concatenated". Unless both usernames and passwords are guaranteed to always be always exactly 20 bytes long (padded with zeroes, maybe).

Comment: you can use "sizeof" to determine the size in bytes of the buffer

Comment: @tux3 Thanks, I reflected this in the answer.

Comment: You better check the length of received buffer. if you got -1, it is an error. Also, after receive the buffer is not null terminated.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have read about that issue while browsing for answers here. So basically, as long as the username doesn't exceed 19 chars it will always work as intended and the username and password will be properly separated right ?

Comment: No, they are not guaranteed to be separated, i.e. to be read by separate calls to `recv`. I would treat SOCK_STREAM mostly as a byte-wide pipe: you write data on one side in chunks of any size you want; inside the pipe, borders between the chunks are eliminated, it's just a contiguous stream of bytes; then you read on the other side in chunks of any size you want (but you may get less then you ask for if the system doesn't have enough data; maybe later it will have some more).